# How to separate character string by a word and adding the word on both sides, using R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df that looks like this (`dput()`at the end of question):

```
id                                                                                 leg_activity
1044                                          home, pt, work, adpt, home, adpt, work, adpt, home
1215                 home, adpt, work, adpt, home, car, outside, car, work, car, work, car, home
1238                                                             home, work, leisure, adpt, home
1458                                          home, outside, pt, home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home
1569 home, car_passenger, leisure, walk, work, walk, leisure, walk, work, adpt, home, walk, home
1615                                          home, adpt, work, walk, work, walk, work, pt, home
```

I want to separate the cells of `leg_activity` into multiple columns. The separation of the character string should occur as soon as `, home` occurs. The idea is to see what happens between two `home` entries. For the first row the desired result would look like this:

```
id      1                              2                                               
1044    home, pt, work, adpt, home     home, adpt, work, adpt, home
```

As you can see, I'd like to keep `home` in both new cells.

My approach so far can not do this, it simply deletes `home` but I need it to appear on both sides of the cut:

```
library(dplyr)

df  <- agents %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(leg_activity, sep = 'home, ') %>% 
  group_by(n, id) %>% 
  mutate(n2 = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(n2, leg_activity) %>%
  select(-n)
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

data to try the code:

```
structure(list(id = c(9L, 10L, 11L, 96L, 97L, 101L, 103L, 248L, 
499L, 1044L, 1215L, 1238L, 1458L, 1569L, 1615L, 1626L, 1734L, 
1735L, 1790L, 1912L, 9040L, 14858L, 14859L, 14967L, 15011L, 15012L, 
15015L, 15045L, 15050L, 15058L, 15060L, 15086L, 15088L, 15094L, 
15109L, 15113L, 15152L, 15157L, 15192L, 15193L, 15222L, 15230L, 
15231L, 15234L, 15235L, 15237L, 15256L, 15257L, 15258L, 15269L
), leg_activity = c("home, adpt, shop, car_passenger, home, adpt, work, adpt, home, work, outside, pt, home", 
"home, pt, outside, pt, home, car, leisure, car, other, car, leisure, car, leisure, car, other, car, leisure, car, other, car, leisure, car, home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home", 
"home, work, adpt, home", "home, car, work, car, home, work, adpt, home", 
"home, adpt, work, car_passenger, leisure, car_passenger, work, adpt, home, car_passenger, outside, car_passenger, outside, car_passenger, home", 
"home, bike, outside, car_passenger, outside, car_passenger, outside, bike, home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home, bike, leisure, bike, home", 
"home, adpt, work, adpt, home, walk, other, pt, home", "home, adpt, work, walk, home, adpt, work, walk, home", 
"home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home, bike, outside, bike, home", 
"home, pt, work, adpt, home, adpt, work, adpt, home", "home, adpt, work, adpt, home, car, outside, car, work, car, work, car, home", 
"home, work, leisure, adpt, home", "home, outside, pt, home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home", 
"home, car_passenger, leisure, walk, work, walk, leisure, walk, work, adpt, home, walk, home", 
"home, adpt, work, walk, work, walk, work, pt, home", "home, car, work, pt, leisure, adpt, work, car, home, car, home", 
"home, adpt, other, adpt, home, car, home", "home, adpt, other, adpt, home", 
"home, education, walk, shop, walk, education, pt, outside, home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home", 
"home, adpt, work, adpt, home, walk, home", "home, adpt, work, pt, leisure, adpt, work, adpt, work, adpt, home, adpt, other, walk, home", 
"home, adpt, work, adpt, home, adpt, work, adpt, home, walk, leisure, walk, home", 
"home, adpt, work, adpt, home, work, adpt, home, walk, leisure, walk, home", 
"home, adpt, work, adpt, home, car_passenger, outside, car_passenger, leisure, car_passenger, home, car_passenger, home", 
"home, adpt, other, adpt, home, car, work, car, home", "home, adpt, education, adpt, leisure, adpt, home, walk, leisure, walk, home", 
"home, car_passenger, other, pt, home, walk, other, walk, home, car_passenger, other, walk, home, adpt, other, adpt, home", 
"home, work, pt, work, adpt, work, adpt, home", "home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home, car, shop, car, other, car, home", 
"home, adpt, work, adpt, home, walk, other, adpt, home", "home, adpt, work, adpt, home, car_passenger, leisure, car_passenger, home", 
"home, car, other, car, home, adpt, shop, adpt, home", "home, pt, work, adpt, home", 
"home, adpt, work, adpt, home", "home, adpt, work, adpt, home", 
"home, walk, education, adpt, home, walk, education, walk, home, bike, leisure, bike, home", 
"home, adpt, shop, adpt, home, car, home", "home, adpt, leisure, walk, leisure, walk, leisure, adpt, home", 
"home, adpt, shop, pt, home, adpt, other, adpt, home", "home, adpt, other, adpt, home, car_passenger, leisure, walk, home", 
"home, adpt, work, adpt, home, car_passenger, shop, car_passenger, home", 
"home, adpt, other, adpt, work, adpt, home", "home, adpt, work, adpt, home, adpt, other, walk, shop, walk, home, car, outside, car, outside, car, outside, car, home", 
"home, adpt, other, adpt, home", "home, adpt, education, adpt, home, adpt, education, adpt, home", 
"home, pt, work, adpt, work, adpt, work, adpt, work, adpt, home, adpt, work, adpt, home", 
"home, walk, other, car_passenger, education, walk, home, car_passenger, education, adpt, home", 
"home, walk, shop, walk, home, walk, leisure, adpt, leisure, adpt, home", 
"home, adpt, work, adpt, home, walk, shop, walk, home, walk, leisure, walk, home, walk, home", 
"home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home")), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`, `stringr` and `tidyr` (or better `tidyverse`):

```r
df %>%
  separate_rows(leg_activity, sep = "home, ") %>%
  mutate(leg_activity = str_replace(leg_activity, "(, (home)*)$", "")) %>%
  filter(leg_activity != "") %>% 
  mutate(leg_activity = str_c("home, ", leg_activity, ", home")) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = n, values_from = leg_activity)
```

I guess, there are better solution, but this should give you your desired output.

```
> df2
# A tibble: 50 x 5
# Groups:   id [50]
      id `1`                           `2`                             `3`           `4`  
   <int> <chr>                         <chr>                           <chr>         <chr>
 1     9 home, adpt, shop, car_passen~ home, adpt, work, adpt, home    home, work, ~ NA   
 2    10 home, pt, outside, pt, home   home, car, leisure, car, other~ home, adpt, ~ NA   
 3    11 home, work, adpt, home        NA                              NA            NA   
 4    96 home, car, work, car, home    home, work, adpt, home          NA            NA   
 5    97 home, adpt, work, car_passen~ home, car_passenger, outside, ~ NA            NA   
 6   101 home, bike, outside, car_pas~ home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home home, bike, ~ NA   
 7   103 home, adpt, work, adpt, home  home, walk, other, pt, home     NA            NA   
 8   248 home, adpt, work, walk, home  home, adpt, work, walk, home    NA            NA   
 9   499 home, adpt, leisure, adpt, h~ home, bike, outside, bike, home NA            NA   
10  1044 home, pt, work, adpt, home    home, adpt, work, adpt, home    NA            NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R version using a custom function.
`split_by_home` creates a list of legs, the final steps ensure all vectors have the same length so they can be combined to a data frame.

```
split_by_home <- apply(df["leg_activity"], 1, function(x) {
  splits <- strsplit(x, split = ", home,")[[1]]
  if(length(splits) >= 1) splits[1] <- paste0(splits[1], ", home")
  if(length(splits) > 2) {
    splits[2:(length(splits) - 1)] <- paste0("home,", splits[2:(length(splits) - 1)], ", home")
    splits[length(splits)] <- paste0("home,", splits[length(splits)])
  }
  if(length(splits) == 2){
    splits[length(splits)] <- paste0("home,", splits[length(splits)])
  }
  return(splits)
}
)

max_length <- max(unlist(lapply(split_by_home, length)))
split_by_home_na <- lapply(split_by_home, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, max_length - length(x))))
split_by_home_df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, split_by_home_na))
final_table <- cbind(df$id, split_by_home_df)
```

```
> final_table[1:10, ]
   df$id                                                                              V1
1      9                                           home, adpt, shop, car_passenger, home
2     10                                                     home, pt, outside, pt, home
3     11                                                    home, work, adpt, home, home
4     96                                                      home, car, work, car, home
5     97       home, adpt, work, car_passenger, leisure, car_passenger, work, adpt, home
6    101 home, bike, outside, car_passenger, outside, car_passenger, outside, bike, home
7    103                                                    home, adpt, work, adpt, home
8    248                                                    home, adpt, work, walk, home
9    499                                                 home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home
10  1044                                                      home, pt, work, adpt, home
                                                                                                                          V2                              V3   V4
1                                                                                               home, adpt, work, adpt, home   home, work, outside, pt, home <NA>
2  home, car, leisure, car, other, car, leisure, car, leisure, car, other, car, leisure, car, other, car, leisure, car, home home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home <NA>
3                                                                                                                       <NA>                            <NA> <NA>
4                                                                                                     home, work, adpt, home                            <NA> <NA>
5                                                  home, car_passenger, outside, car_passenger, outside, car_passenger, home                            <NA> <NA>
6                                                                                            home, adpt, leisure, adpt, home home, bike, leisure, bike, home <NA>
7                                                                                                home, walk, other, pt, home                            <NA> <NA>
8                                                                                               home, adpt, work, walk, home                            <NA> <NA>
9                                                                                            home, bike, outside, bike, home                            <NA> <NA>
10                                                                                              home, adpt, work, adpt, home                            <NA> <NA>
```